# How to get customer shopping cart information using sql query

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, shopping-cart

How to get customer shopping cart information using custom sql query.

I want to get shopping cart product information like below.

for example ::

> product_name,
>                  product_id,
>                  product_image,
>                  qty,
>                  row_total,
>                  is_in_stock,
>                  base_subtotal,
>                  base_grand_total,
>                  shipping_amount,
>                  street

Comment: why you need sql query you can get all data via magento syntax

Comment: I am new in magento. I have a this task so please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

you can get current customer cart/quote  detail from below code

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())  ;
   echo $product->getName();

}
```

you can get all data from `$product` as it is a product object so you can easily access product data

Comment: Thanks,
But I want to get cart information using custom sql query.

Comment: you get cart information from this code

Comment: Yes I know but i want to cart information using custom sql query.
so please suggest me.

Comment: why you need custom query ?? please tell me so I can provide you better answer

Comment: I have get a this task. so please

Answer (score -1):

You can get the code for it in

> app/design/frontend/[Your-package]/[Your-theme]/template/Checkout/Cart

There you will find snippet like this

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```